# VBA code to look for value copy value next to it and paste in different cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA coding, I looking for a way to find a specific text in column A after it finds it, copy the next available word next to it (Column C) and paste it in A10 cell inside of the same worksheet.

I found a code here at Stack Overflow which finds the words that I'm looking for on column A, it tells me what is the next value on column C but I can't make it paste on the cell A10.

Now, since there is multiple titles next to the word: "Title_product", I would like that every time it finds the title on column C, it adds a "AND" to its finding. For example: on column A we have 2 rows that has the word "Title_product" and the book title on Column C is Book 1 and Book 2. I would like the value in Cell A10 to be: "Book 1 and Book 2" If this is too much don't worry, It helps if it could paste the title from column C somewhere inside of the worksheet then I could Excel formula.

```
This is the code that I was trying to modify:
Public Sub FindingValues()
Dim val As Variant
val = "Title_product"
Set c = Cells.Find(val, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
If Not c Is Nothing Then
    Do
        MsgBox "Value of val is found at " & c.Address & vbCrLf & c.Offset(0, 1).Value & vbCrLf & c.Offset(0, 2).Value
        Set c = Cells.FindNext(c)
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstaddress
End If
End Sub
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: What happens if you find the same value in two cells in column `A` but the corresponding values in column `C` are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have accidentally deleted the line `firstAddress = c.Address` - as is, `firstAddress` is just a zero-length `String`.

That aside, add a `result` variable that concatenates together the values from Column C when "*Title_Product*" is found in Column A. Then write the `result` to `Range("A10")` after the loop.

```
Public Sub FindingValues()
    Dim val As String, result As String, firstAddress As String
    Dim c As Range

    val = "Title_product"
    Set c = Sheets("MySheetName").Range("A:A").Find(val, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address

        Do
            If Len(result) > 0 Then
                result = result & " and " & c.Offset(, 2).Text
            Else
                result = c.Offset(, 2).Text
            End If

            Set c = Cells.FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If

    Sheets("MySheetName").Range("A10").Value = result
End Sub
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

I tackled this problem a different way by just iterating through column A instead of using `Find`. One thing to note is that if you are searching through column A, and also printing your output into column A, that may be an issue: I'd consider printing your output elsewhere (e.g. change `outputCell` to somewhere else).

```
Sub FindingValues()
Dim valStr As String, found() As String, outputStr As String
Dim outputCell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Long, foundCt As Long, lastRow As Long

'define the sheet to be worked on
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

'define the output cell
Set outputCell = ws.Cells(10, 1) 'A10

'define the text to search for
valStr = "Title_product"

'find last row to use
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'change the array size to match the number of possible results
ReDim found(lastRow) As String

'loop through all cells in column A
For x = 1 To lastRow

    'check cells in column A for valStr
    If InStr(LCase(ws.Cells(x, 1).Text), LCase(valStr)) Then

        'if found, store found values in array
        foundCt = foundCt + 1
        found(foundCt) = ws.Cells(x, 3).Text

    End If

Next x

'format the output based on the number of found items
'(Book 1 | Book 1 and Book 2 | Book 1, Book 2, and Book 3)

'if no results were found
If found(1) = "" Then
    outputStr = "..."

'if one result was found
ElseIf found(1) <> "" And found(2) = "" Then
    outputStr = found(1)

'if two results were found
ElseIf found(1) <> "" And found(2) <> "" And found(3) = "" Then
    outputStr = found(1) & " and " & found(2)

'if three or more results were found
Else
    outputStr = found(1)
    For x = 2 To foundCt - 1
        outputStr = outputStr & ", " & found(x)
    Next x
    outputStr = outputStr & ", and " & found(foundCt)
End If

'print the output to the output cell
outputCell.Formula = outputStr

End Sub
```